# VBA How to save as file with date after open

Tags: vba

I wanted to save the file which is set = Workbook open with the date, however it saves this file for me as a tmp file. Where do I go wrong?

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(MyFolder & "\" & MyFile, UpdateLinks:=0)
MyFolder1 = "\\bank.ad.pkobp.pl\dfs\DaneGrupowe\BH\BPR\Wlasne\003_Adekwatność_kapitałowa\_Beata_replacement\_KROK_4_COREP_ITS\Robocze\macro"
wb.SaveAs (MyFolder1 & Format(Date, ddmmyyyy) & ".xls"))
```

Comment: You need to put quotes around the format: `Format(Date, "ddmmyyyy")`, else VBA is looking for a variable named `ddmmyyyy` (always use `Option Explicit` to avoid such problems)

Comment: @FunThomas Thanks i changed and its saved file, but how to add for example name and date to file` wb.SaveAs (MyFolder1 & Format(Now(), "wb") & ".xls")`

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

```
Filename = "CMR_CJ_MINIMAL_"
```

MyFolder1 = "xxx\xxx"
wb.SaveAs (MyFolder1 & Filename & Format(Now(), "MM.YYYY") & ".xlsx")